# Creating a one to one association with sequelize nodejs and postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am currently working a project using **NodeJS** and **postgresql** with **Sequelize** as the ORM.

I have two tables; and **address table** and a **user table**. I want the address primary key to be a foreign key in the user table.

THIS is how I have defined the association.

```
Address.hasOne(User);
User.belongsTo(Address, {
foreignKey:{
  type:Sequelize.IMTEGER,
  name: "address_id",
  allowNull: false,
  },
  });
```

This is the definition of my address table using sequelize;

```
exports default (sequelize, DataTypes) =>{
const Address = sequelize.define("address ",{
address_id:{
type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
autoIncrement:true,
primaryKey: true,
unique:true
},
address_name:{
type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
allowNull: false,
validate:{
notNull:{
 msg: "address name required!"
}
}
});
return Address;
}
```

And this is the user table:

```
exports default (sequelize, DataTypes) =>{
const User = sequelize.define("user ",{
user_id:{
type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
autoIncrement:true,
primaryKey: true,
unique:true
},
name:{
type: DataTypes.STRING,
allowNull: false,
validate:{
notNull:{
 msg: "Name required!"
}
}
});
return User;
}
```

But when I run the **synchronization**,  all the other **columns** get created except for the **address_id** column I expect in the User table.

I need help!
Thank everyone in advance

Answer (score 0):

At least you need to indicate the same value for `foreignKey` option in both associations:

```js
Address.hasOne(User, { foreignKey: 'address_id' });
User.belongsTo(Address, , { foreignKey: 'address_id' });
```

And it's better to explicitly define `address_id` in `User` model:

```js
address_id:{
type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
notNull: true
},
```